# Can not access mongodb atlas from mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, connectivity

I have set up a project in MongoDB atlas and created a user, followed the process as described in the documentation to white list IP, etc. However, I am not able to connect from my laptop.
Error is:
`"HostNotFound: Could not find address for cluster0-6lzea.mongodb.net:27017: SocketException: No such host is known."`

I have referred to similar questions, 2 of them were similar but their issue was because they dint white list the ip and another was blocked by universities' firewall.  I do not have both the issues as I have whitelisted IP and I am not behind any firewall.

Comment: Issue got resolved!!.  Documentation was wrong.      Instead of the string given for mongo version 4.2   I used the string given for version 3.4 and below!!..

Comment: Below is the format for reference.   mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-6lzea.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-6lzea.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-6lzea.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin  --username test_user --password <password>

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra, this is likely because you are using `mongo` shell version 3.4 and below. I would recommend to upgrade your local installation of MongoDB to be able to use the new SRV connection string.